# Autoencoding, using encoding and decoding layers in Keras, Tensorflow- issues in defining latent layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, autoencoder

I've been following a convolutional autoencoder, derived from https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-convolutional-autoencoder-using-keras-using-conv2dtranspose-ca403c8d144e using a data set of 72x72 greyscale images. I've been able to obtain a trainable model, but have been getting issues in applying it to my data.

Convolution/deconvolution:

```
input = Input(shape=(72,72,1))

e_input = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input) #70 70 32
e = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(e_input) #35 35 32
e = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(e) #33 33 64
e = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(e) # 16 16 64
e = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(e) #16 16 64
e = Flatten()(e) #1 1 12544
e_output = Dense(324, activation='softmax')(e) #1 1 324

d = Reshape((18,18,1))(e_output) #18 18 1, found to be generally N/4 units (so 7 for 28x28)
d = Conv2DTranspose(64,(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(d) #36 36 64
d = Conv2DTranspose(64,(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(d) #72 72 64
d = Conv2DTranspose(64,(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d) #72 72 64
d_output = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(d) #72 72 1
```

And here's the code for separate encoding and decoding, as well as defining the autoencoder model:

```
autoencoder = Model(input, d_output) 
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["mae"]) 
encoder = Model(input, e_output) 
encoded_input = Input(shape=(1,1)) 
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-6](encoded_input)
l2 = autoencoder.layers[-5](decoder_layer) 
decoder = Model(encoded_input, l2)
```

Following training, I inputted the following, wherein x_train is (2433, 72, 72).

```
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_train)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

And I obtain the error for decoded_imgs: "*ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 1), found shape=(None, 324)*", but changing encoded_input's shape to (324) gives rise to another error (*ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "dense_2" (type Dense).*) in calling back layers in decoded_layer...

I speculate I'm not reshaping data at the correct time, or perhaps I'm unnecessarily using some models. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of the decoder is the output of the encoder. In the model the shape of the encoder's output is `(None, 324)` but you are passing an input of shape `(1, 1)`. The shape of the latent layer is `(None, 324)`. You can create a separate decoder model as follows:

```
decoder=Model(e_output, d_output)
```

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/e73c2803260c685d8e23d86306b88d88/untitled102.ipynb). Thank you!